# Hibernate Max value for each group

Tags: hibernate, group-by, max

I am new to Hibernate. Mapping between my table and class is given like this.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>  
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"  
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.pathfinder.beans.Location" table="VEHICLE_LOCATIONS">
        <id name="rowId" column="position_id">
            <generator class="native"></generator>
        </id>
        <property name="vehicleId" column="VEHICLE_ID"></property>
        <property name="latitude" column="LATITUDE"></property>
        <property name="longitude" column="LONGITUDE"></property>
        <property name="time" column="TIME"></property>
        <property name="createdtime" column="CREATEDTIME"></property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Now i need to get latitude, longitude, time for each vehicleId with latest createdtime. With an sql query, I can get it like

```
SELECT a.vehicle_id, a.latitude, a.longitude, a.time
FROM vehicle_locations a
LEFT JOIN  vehicle_locations b ON a.vehicle_id = b.vehicle_id AND a.createdtime < b.createdtime
WHERE b.position_id IS NULL;
```

But when i try same join in HQL, it gives an error like

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: DOT node with no left-hand-side!

How can i get expected results using hibernate?

Answer (score 1):

you can try with below HQL

```
select a.vehicle_id, a.latitude, a.longitude, a.time 
FROM vehicle_locations a
LEFT JOIN vehicle_locations b with a.vehicle_id = b.vehicle_id AND a.createdtime < b.createdtime
WHERE b.position_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: thanks user3257248, this is pure sql way of handling this issue. Is there a hibernate version for the same? how can we make hibernate generate the same query using Object and its properies? (without using relational tables, and its columns)